# Google's Chrome auto adds background-color:yellow to element.style

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

This is not a duplicate of the auto fill for input. 
My problem is that chrome has been adding background-color:yellow (that i DID NOT include in my code) to some of my elements on the page.This is quite annoying. I opened the same page in incognito and it doesn't have that problem. 
Seeing that most users use chrome as default browser, it'll be quite discouraging for them to encounter this issue.
This issue doesn't happen on other browsers. I've used Opera and Edge to check
I've attached screenshots.
I've tried overwriting with css !important rule but to no avail. I even tried using javascript to do so.

chrome with the yellow background

[image]

chrome in incognito mode

[image]

same code on opera

[image]

Comment: On `google chrome` (press f12 for chrome developer) setting, try to disable `javascript` in debugger section and reload your page again.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like some of your chrome plugins did that. You could disable them one by one to find out which plugin did that.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'd do that. Much appreciated.